# connect a javascript button with a php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i am working on my final year project and got stuck on this thing 
i have tried a lot of suggestions from stackoverflow but no results 
i have made a map that displays markers from the database 
sent by arduino ...
[see this photo of the map at imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBJG4.jpg)
 so what i need is to be able to delete these markers from the database  with a button(delete all the rows of the table when the button is clicked or PREFERABLY TO HIDE THEM but i don't know how to do it it seems that i need another file that interact with the database ) and i have link it to delete.php  using  jquery  but it does not work :here is my html code for the page 
please  read the comment first to notice what change i have made 
and for the delete.php script :
and thank you in advance

```html
<?php
$host = "localhost"; //MySQL Host. If you have trouble connecting try "localhost"
$user = "...."; //MySQL username
$password = "...."; //Password for MySQL username Edpzrztkskdwrsardgymzdazfrzwo6
$db_name = "...."; //Name of the db
$table = "statut"; //Name of the table in db

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $db_name);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// sql to delete a record
$sql = "DELETE FROM statut";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Record deleted successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>carte de porte source tanger</title>
      <style>
      html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
      #panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 8px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -190px;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color:#058aff;
        padding: 2px;
        border: 1px solid #058aff;
        border-radius: 3px;
        font-family:Arial;
        font-size:17px;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>// i have add this to be able to use jquery
    <script type="text/javascript">


    //  this is  needed for showing the map 

    var customIcons = {
      
        icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png'};

    function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.7672700 ,-5.7997500),
        zoom: 13,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
        });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("xml.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var nom_poste = markers[i].getAttribute("nom_poste");
          var ts = markers[i].getAttribute("ts");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html ="<b> Date/heure : </b>"+ ts +"<b> GMT </b>"+ "</br>"+"<b> nom de poste : </b> "+nom_poste ;
          var icon = customIcons || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon
          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }
    function deleteMarkers() { //deleteMarkers declaration 
    $.get("delete.php");// calling the delete.php script
    return false;
}

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}

    //]]>

  </script>

  </head>

  <body onload="load()">
      <div id="panel">
<a href="#" onclick="deleteMarkers();">Click Me!</a>    // call the method deletemarkers when the button is clicked 
    
    </div>
    <div id="map" style="width: 1366px; height: 666px"></div>

    
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: "but it does not work". Can you please elaborate on that? What doesn't work? How do you know it doesn't work? What would you expect to happen? What happens instead? Are any errors produced? Is the function `deleteMarkers()` being executed at all? Does the AJAX query get sent? What is the response? Is it what you would expect it to be? Does PHP correctly connect to the database? Go through your own logic and be specific about what is going wrong. Nobody can read your mind.

Comment: i think the problem is in the connection between the Button and the database and i can not localize it because i never leaned about AJAX and jQuery so i post it here in hope that someone can help me

Comment: Try looking at the actual request. If you use chrome push F12, then click on the network tab, then you will see any ajax (XHR) requests there. If you click on it, you can see what you sent and what was received from the server.

Comment: ok i will try it now but do you think that the delete.php call at removemarkers() is right  ?

Comment: when i pressed at F12 noting happens try it  so maybe there is something missed or wrong in hte method http://amendismap.esy.es/map/carte_amendisavec%20bouttonbienfine.html#

Comment: The last tab is called "Console". It has several errors. Your document also doesn't have a `<html>` tag.

Comment: your right but i don't know how to solve the problem :(                                             please help

Comment: The problem is that your web host is returning a HTTP response code 200 for nonexistent resources and then using a meta refresh to a 404 page. That is quite absurd on their part. Probably sufficient for me to change hosts unless they fix this ridiculous behavior. The problem is jquery is not being loaded. http://amendismap.esy.es/map/jquery.min.js "does not exist"... or at least it *should* be returning a 404 response code.

Comment: Here's what's happening: http://www.rexswain.com/cgi-bin/httpview.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Famendismap.esy.es%2Fmap%2Fjquery.min.js&req=Get&ver=1.1&fmt=Auto&uag=&ref=&aen=&fwd=on

Comment: so the problem is in the hosting ? can i test this with wamp server ? and thank you for your guidance Mike

Comment: The hosting is not the problem, but it prevents you from detecting the problem. The problem is that your jquery file doesn't exist. You need to upload it to the correct location or adjust y our html accordingly.

Comment: it's true i didn't upload any jquery file so what should i write on it ? what extention should it have .php or what? and for the html adjustement so maybe  the method deleteMarkers() does not zork properly ? and please forgive me Mike noob questions

Comment: Just replace that whole line with `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` and use the Google CDN instead.

Comment: do you mean to replace <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>    WITH    google CDN wich is <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>    ??

Comment: still no result Mike should i replace all the tree lines or just the one in the previous comment

Comment: You are trying to get jquery to work. So put that line in your <head> and get rid of the other line with the invalid URL to jquery.

Comment: so i make it like this : <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>carte de porte source tanger</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

Comment: please can you check the method deleteMarkers()    i think the problem on it

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by making these changes to delete method :but still stuck on how to stay at the same page when executing the php script i think i should use AJAX but i don't know how

```html
  <a href="delete.php" onclick="return deleteMarkers();" />Delete</a>
```

```js
 function deleteMarkers(){ 
    var question = confirm("Are you sure?");
    if(question){

    return true;

    }else{

    alert("Thanks for not choosing to delete");
    return false;

    }

    }
```